# In Access, How to pick a date range instead of typing two date parameter?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In the Access, i tried to run the query that showing the payroll data between two date. Currently, I need to type two date at the input box. However, I want to use date picker to pick two date to generate the same result. Anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: I don't think access have a date range picker. You will have to build one yourself

Comment: since Access 2007 there's a built-in datepicker. Just set properties on the control to say it is a date if it is unbound. Controls bound to date fields automatically enable the date picker.

Comment: Don't use query's *Enter Parameter* which is a nice way of saying your query has a value without a source which is really an error. Use a form with a date picker on textbox and a trigger event (i.e., button) to pass such values to SQL.

Comment: @litelite Could you tell me how to build the range picker?